# Origin of double phonetic component 静

Tags: etymology, character-components

静 is another character that has confused me. 青 (green/blue) doesn't seem to be related to quietness or stillness, unless the colors are supposed to represent quietness?
争 (fight) certainly is not quiet at all! However both 青 and 争 seem to fit as a phonetic component. Wondering how did this character come about? Is this another phonetic loan character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, 「靜」 ([Zhengzhang OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Zhengzhang_(1981%E2%80%931995)): **/*zleŋʔ/**, *calm/quiet*) is a phonetic loan character, and both its components 「青」 (**/*sʰleːŋ/**) and 「爭」 (**/*ʔsreːŋ/**) are phonetic components.

---

Unfortunately, the inscription record is rather scarce and by itself may not actually represent the language that well. Based on the usage of 「靜」, the meaning *calm/quiet* may have been a semantic extension from the meaning *pacify* (**/*zleŋʔ/**, now written 「靖」)*. From [*Guǐ* vessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gui_(vessel)) of Máo Bān [毛班] (班簋,《殷周金文集成》4341):

<sub>*Note how 「靖」 actually has the same reconstructed sound as 「靜」, indicating that there is a strong possibility that they're the same word.</sub>

[image: 班簋]

> 。。。。。。王令毛公㠯（以）邦（冢）君，土（徒），（馭），⿰⿱口十戈（戜）人伐東或（國、域）㾶（滑）戎。咸。王令吳白（伯）曰：“㠯乃（師）⿸口（左）比毛父。”王令呂白曰：“㠯乃（右）比毛父。”⿻夭遣（遣）令曰：”㠯乃族從父征。“⿰彳⿱止口（城）衛父身，三秂（年） **`靜`** 東或，亾（無）不成⿱白尤（尤），天（畏 > 威），否（丕）⿱甶大（畀）屯（純）陟。。。。。。
>
> *...The King* ([King Mù of Zhōu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Mu_of_Zhou)) *ordered Máo Bān to command the [vassals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fengjian) and their infantry, chariots, and [auxiliaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliaries) to attack the tribes of the eastern regions in armed rebellion. Thus it is so. The King ordered the Vassal of [Wú](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_(state)): "Lead your troops in assistance of Elder General Máo* (Máo Bān's father) *from the left side." The King ordered the Vassal of [Lǚ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BC_(state)): "Lead your troops in assistance of Elder General Máo from the right side." [Duke Chéng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Guo)* (虢城公遣) *ordered Máo Bān: "Lead your clansmen to closely follow the expedition of Elder General Máo." Thus, I* (Máo Bān, caster of this vessel) *firmly guarded my father in this expedition. In three years, the eastern regions were **pacified**, and not once have I committed a military blunder. By the might and grace of [Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tian), who has bestowed me these rewards, I have risen to this great position...*

Since the usage speaks of *military pacification*, one might analyse 「靜」 (**/*zleŋʔ/**, *to pacify*) to be comprised of simultaneously semantic and phonetic 「爭」 (**/*ʔsreːŋ/**, *to fight, contend*) and phonetic 「青」 (**/*sʰleːŋ/**). *Military pacification* was later extended to mean *peace, calm, quiet*.

---

**References:**

- 中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》
- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 劉翔・陳抗・陳初生・董琨　編　李學勤　審訂《商周古文字讀本》

Answer (score 0):

[image] [image]

1. 無紛亂亦曰靜 - "No Chaos" also called "靜"
2. 安靜本字當從立部之竫 - character '靜' in '安靜' (quiet) originally was '竫'
3. 靜
4. 審也 - to define
5. 丹青明審也 - 丹(color of south) + 青 (color of East) = 明審(clearly defined)

~

- The character 靜 is made up of 青 and 爭. Both semantic and phonetic component
- The 青 component in 靜 represents 丹青 -- (青 is color of the East; 丹 is color of the south. 丹 + 青 = clearly defined)
- 靜 has the extended meaning of 審 (to define; make clear) and 爭 is the phonetic component
- *"No Chaos" also called "靜"* -- when chaos is sorted out, we get tranquilness - [青(clear)爭(chaos)]
- The original character for 靜 in 清靜 (quiet) was 竫